# check string function

Tags: php

I am currently trying to get my head around some basic php string functions. I currently use this code which determines if the username entered in long enough e.g.:

```
    if (strlen($_GET['name']) < 3) {
        echo 'First Name should be at least 3 characters long!';
        exit;
    }
```

And this works just fine. Which string function should I use though if I want to to check on a specific name? E.g. I would like to trigger a message once someone enters a specific Word in the form field.

Some expert advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to trigger a message immediately you should consider using javascript you cannot do that by php without a server roundtrip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a function for that. You can use a `if` statement and `==`:

```
if ( $_GET['name'] == 'Dave' )
{
  // user entered 'Dave'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This link of [60 PHP validation functions](http://www.maheshchari.com/60-validation-functions-with-php/) is an excelent resource.

For your case as to check a name, you could use something like:

```
if (strtolower($_GET['name']) === 'joe') {
  // Do something for Joe
}

elseif (in_array(strtolower($_GET['name']), array('dave', 'bob', 'jane')) {
  // Do something else for Dave, Bob or Jane
}
```

The `strtolower` will ensure that upper, lower or mixed case names will match.

Comment: As @LawrenceCherone mentions, it is always good practice to check that the variable is available with either `!empty()` or `isset()` to prevent filling your logs with messages if the variable is not available.

Answer (score 2):

`if` statement, or if you plan to check against multiple names, `switch()`.

```
switch($_GET['name']){
    case "Eric":
        //Eric
    break;
    case "Sally":
        //Sally
    break;
    case "Tom":
        //Tom
    break;
    default:
        //Unknown
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its good practice to check that `$_GET['name']` is set before using. To answer your question a good way IMO is `in_array(needle,haystack)`

```
<?php 

 if (!empty($_GET['name']) && strlen($_GET['name']) < 3) {
        echo 'First Name should be at least 3 characters long!';
        exit;
 }

 //From a database or preset
 $names = array('Bob','Steve','Grant');
 if(in_array($_GET['name'], $names)){
    echo 'Name is already taken!';
    exit;
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **strstr** or **stristr**(case-insensitive) function, If want to search for specific word in a sentence.

Just check php mannual for [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php), and [stristr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php).